# Decomposition in the ring Z[i]

Tags: number-theory

How do I decompose $a=11-7i$ in the ring $Z[i]$?
I know that the norm of $a$, $N(a) = 170$, thus for $x+yi$ that divides $a$, $N(x+yi) = x^2+y^2$ and thus $x^2+y^2$ divides $170$.

$x^2 + y^2$ is either $2, 5$, or $17$ and then $x+yi$ is of the form:

$1+-i, 1+-2i, 2+-i, 1+-4i, 4+-i$.

How do I get to the final answer without checking all of these?
Thanks for all the help.

Comment: $1+i$ and $1-i$ are associated, $1+i = i(1-i)$. Then you just need to see whether $2+i$ divides $11-7i$ or not. The quotient $\dfrac{11-7i}{(1+i)(2\pm i)}$ then tells you whether it's $4+i$ or $4-i$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $170 = 17 * 10$ and both of these are norms, something like $(1+4i)(1+3i)$ will do and then you just have to fiddle around with signs. Looks like $-(1 + 4i)(1+3i)$ will do (edit: got the signs wrong in first post!)

Comment: Those can be further decomposed. In general, $$11-7i = -1 \cdot (1+i)\cdot (2+i)\cdot (1+4i)$$